# TypeScript targets wrong ECMAScript version

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2017

Suddently, at least it feels that way, my VS17 started transpiling my TypeScript to ECMAScript 6, but VS will not accept it and throws a lot of SCRIPT1002 and SCRIPT1006 errors all of a sudden: "JavaScript critical error at line 3, column 5 in http://localhost:57125/Scripts/js/Modules/Test.js\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error"

I have this very simplified TS module:

```
module Test {
    export class TestObject {
        Data: string;
    }
}
```

It transpiles to

```
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    class TestObject {
    }
Test.TestObject = TestObject;
})(Test || (Test = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=Test.js.map
```

But Visual Studio complains that `class` is a syntactical error.

What it should output (and has done up until sometime last week) is

```
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    var TestObject = (function () {
        function TestObject() {
        }
        return TestObject;
    }());
    Test.TestObject = TestObject;
})(Test || (Test = {}));
```

I am sure that VS (or maybe IE11?) expects ECMAScript 5 but changing the version in the project properties does nothing for me (ECMAScript 3, 5, 6, 2016, 2017, and Next). I have TS 2.8, 3.0 and 3.1 installed. Changing this does nothing either. Module system is set to AMD, but this does not change anything for me. Either..

How can I fix this? I have restarted VS multiple times and I have even restarted my computer in case some stupid process didn't die with VS.

Comment: VS Tooling is shifting over to the tsconfig.json file for settings and are ending with their .csproj typescript settings. There was some time in between where both were allowed and the compiler had some strange strategies for what config it should use. (Sounds like your case). Try and remove the tsconfig settings in the .csproj file or just ignore them and add a tsconfig.json file. 
You can read more about the tsconfig format here. 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: @PerSvensson I do not have any tsconfig file, so unfortunately it can't be that. I did look at the structure and found that the settings are in the csproj file, so I guess my project is up to date on that part.

Comment: @PerSvensson Also, if I could read what you wrote, I would say I am no up to date on that part.. But editing the settings from VS does not generate a new tsconfig file so there should not be anything to confuse the poor compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I caused the problem. CTRL+F5 in IE fixed it.

---

Recently I changed the ES version to 6 because of some syntax I wanted to use. I never finished the code and two days ago I picked it up again. It worked fine the first two debug sessions, probably because I didn't change anything. Suddently it stopped working.

Changing back to ES5 did nothing - the code behind the error remained at ES6. I wanted to check the other transpiled JS and found that the JS was ES5, which got me thinking that it could be a caching problem.

Sure enough, IE cached the ES6 JS and reported the file contents back to VS, along with the error messages. CTRL + F5 = 0 problems.

By the way, I found that IE only support ES5.

Thanks to IE for eating a day and a half away.